# Custom price.phtml file for product view template

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, template, ee-1.12

How do I create a custom `price.phtml` file and display it on the product view page?

Use case: I have updated the `price.phtml` file under product > view to add rich snippets / structured data. And, I would like to create a new `price.phtml` file so that I can use it for 'Related Products' which appear on the Product View page.

=== Update ===

I have updated catalog.xml as below,

```
<catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="right">  
            <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="relatedProducts" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/related.phtml"> 
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
                <block type="enterprise_targetrule/catalog_product_item" name="catalog.product.related.item" template="targetrule/catalog/product/list/related/item.phtml">  
                     <action method="addPriceBlockType">  
                        <type>simple</type>  
                        <block name="myprice">catalog/product_price</block>  
                        <template>catalog/product/myprice.phtml</template>  
                    </action>                     
                </block>  
            </block>  
        </reference>  
</catalog_product_view>
```

Note that I have only added the simple price type block for now. And, the default related products block is being overridden by a module (as you can see in the above XML).

In myprice.phtml, I just have a simple echo statement.

As a follow up, can I call the custom price template in the related item block as below?

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myprice'); ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Ugh. So messy.

1. Create your custom price template(s) as desired
2. Determine which block is "the related products block"; `catalog.product.related.item` works on a stock theme.
3. For each product type (simple, configurable, etc.), add a price block template as needed.

You can test this out in your custom theme's *layout.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="catalog.product.related.item">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>catalog/product_price</block>
                <template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```